# store message from kafka to hdfs

Tags: python, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm using confluent-Kafka with python.
I want to connect Kafka to Hdfs and store some particular data direct in Hdfs.
I found the confluent HDFS connector, but I didn't get how to connect it with my python script.
any idea ? or any alternative methods to store messages directly from Kafka to Hdfs?

Answer (score 1):

To get data from Kafka to data stores such as HDFS use Kafka Connect (which is part of Apache Kafka).

You need to run an Apache Kafka worker (a JVM process, just like the Kafka broker etc) and then you pass it the configuration for the connector that you want to use in JSON form using the REST API.

Learn more about Kafka Connect in the docs [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-08&utm_term=rmoff-devx) or [this talk](https://rmoff.dev/ljc-kafka-02) and the HDFS connector itself including a quickstart tutorial [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/index.html#quick-start?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-08&utm_term=rmoff-devx).

Answer (score 1):

> I didn't get how to connect it with my python script

Kafka Connect is written in Java, so you cannot integrate with Python. If the documentation could be more clear on this, you should let somebody know.

That being said, it does have a REST API. You would use `requests` or `urllib.request` to interact with it from Python, just as any other HTTP service

---

You could also use PySpark / Flink / Beam to transfer data from Kafka to HDFS **in Python**